# is there any ready land-address regex matcher in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of strings.
Does someone knows if there is a website that has some ready to use 
regex matches\validators in c# to popular land-address formats?

like:

```
<word_street>_<1-3digits>, <alphabetic_word_City>,<country> 

st <alphabetic_word_Street>
```

and so on..

Comment: You might be better off by verifying addresses using a web service or database.  I suspect there will be oddball address that won't pass.

Comment: You're not going to get a regex to do a good job of address validation - it's too complex. If you insist on trying, then make sure you handle addresses like "100-28 205th Place".

Comment: If this is for static validation and you're okay with strict verification, regex might be possible, but quite complex.  If you're talking about user input, especially to implement a search, then writing this in regex will be an intractable problem.  It isn't typo-friendly enough.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham it's for static (hebrew - possible ??) strings. Actually I need to fetch some addresses from a given text. Thought to use some common regex.

Comment: @EladBenda: If you have a specific text or template, then it might be better to match *around* the address, or some guaranteed area the address will be in, then trim that up, rather than trying to match the address directly.

Comment: Just pass the sucker unparsed to Google Maps and dig out the resulting coordinates. That's the best address parser in the whole intertubes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here http://regexlib.com I have found some usable regular expressions there ,  not sure about your request because i didn't understood exactly what you mean by  and

on the other hand if you are need the country i don't think that regular expression is your solution (Hard to maintain)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to match Hebrew charachters?